# Question concerning Firebase Fire Store Rules

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

A few months ago I made a linked-in clone using firebase and then google sent me an email about a week after it had been created saying the site had been flagged for malicious activity or something. Either it was legitimate and someone hacked it or it may have flagged my site as fishing due to it being a clone, I don't know. I am now creating a new application that is similar in nature to the linked-in clone. The user signs in using Firebase Auth and then they can post using firebase firestore. I think my previous rules for firestore were to lax so I made some new ones. Will the rules below prevent this from happening again?

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{postId} {
     // Only authenticated users can read or write to the "posts" collection
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  
     // Only the owner of the post can update or delete it
     allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
  
     // Only authenticated users can create new posts
     allow create: if request.auth != null
               && request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(['title', 'content'])
               && request.resource.data.title is string
               && request.resource.data.content is string
               && request.resource.data.title.size() > 0
               && request.resource.data.content.size() > 0
               && request.resource.data.keys().size() == 2;
   }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This will not do what you want: the 2 rules below will neven be used as the first one will always pass for an authenticated user. Moreover, you are not setting the uid field on creation. Try this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{postId} {
     // Only authenticated users can read to the "posts" collection
      allow read: if request.auth != null;  // Removed 'write' here
  
     // Only the owner of the post can update or delete it
     allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
  
     // Only authenticated users can create new posts
     allow create: if request.auth != null
               && request.resource.data.title is string
               && request.resource.data.content is string
               && request.resource.data.title.size() > 0    // You may want to put an upper limit here
               && request.resource.data.content.size() > 0  // Same
               && request.resource.data.size() == 3
               && request.resource.data.uid = request.auth.uid;   // Important!
   }
 }
```